# Laravel problem no commands defined in the "package" namespace, after $ php artisan config:clear

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, config

Help! My laravel project was working perfectly. And I accidently clear the config like this.
$ php artisan config:clear

Now I can't even run it or reinstall. This is the error message I got.
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating optimized autoload files

> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

There are no commands defined in the "package" namespace.

Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

Thnak you in advance :)

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Also try deleting `vendor` and running `composer install` again

Comment: I'm using Laravel 7. And composer install is not working. I always have the same message errors "No commands defines in the package namespace"